# System-wide unique filename in fortran

Tags: multiprocessing, fortran, intel-fortran

I have a fortran program that needs to find the filename that case-insensitively matches 'my_file'

To do this I use the following command:

`call system "find -ipath '*my_file' > " // trim(tmp_name)`

whereafter I read the contents of tmp_name

When running multiple instances of the program, they fails because all instances write to the same file.

I have not succeeded with the following solutions:

- obtain output from system without saving to file
- add random number to filename (does not work as the random numbers are not unique between instances started at the same time, even with `CALL RANDOM_INIT (REPEATABLE=.FALSE., IMAGE_DISTINCT=.TRUE.)`)
- open a scratch file and then use the name of the file (does not work as the scratch files were not named)
- run within `!$omp critical(critical_generate_temp_name)` block

Any ideas?

Comment: You may call [tempnam](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/tempnam.html) using a C binding. It exists both on Linux and [Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/tempnam-wtempnam-tmpnam-wtmpnam).

Comment: It's not clear from what you write whether the file exists and the Fortran program just has to find/use it, or the Fortran program is responsible for creating the file. Can you expand on the work process? (Note that generating temporary files for communication is an area where security considerations exist in best practice. As a rule: don't create temporary files with predictable names unless you have good reason.)

Comment: There are also C (hence usable in Fortran) to read the contents of a directory. It may be simpler, especially if you don't have many places to search.

Comment: @francescalus the application calls external dlls/so files. Their names are input via a text file and we want same behaviour on windows and linux. I.e. the task is to find the right filename on linux if the input name contains wrong upper/lower case characters. I assume it would be easier for an attacker to change the input than the content of a temp file that only lives until the contents is read in the next line. 
tempnam or listing the directory via c would probably also work, but I think, adding the pid to the filename is a fine solution for the current task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly include the PID (process ID) into the file name. Intel Fortran, and some other compilers, have the [`GETPID()`](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/fortran-compiler-oneapi-dev-guide-and-reference/top/language-reference/a-to-z-reference/g-1/getpid.html) function from the `IFPORT` module (can be also a [non-standard intrinsic](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/GETPID.html) in other compilers), but you can also use `GET_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE()` instead and inquire the `PID` environment variable value (a string that you can append to your file name).

The PID should be unique at any given time, but will repeat in the future after the original process terminated. ([PID reuse possibility in Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/414971/pid-reuse-possibility-in-linux))

You can also include the date and time.

---

This is a quick an dirty pragmatic solution to get the job done quickly that may be insecure in certain multi-user (or already compromised) systems. Other answers with other approaches are welcome.

Comment: Including a PID in the file name may suit the person who asked this question, but other readers should consider the massive security hole that this can introduce to their work.

Comment: I really considered the most common use of Fortran for scientific or engineering computation where if the system has a malicious user in action with access to the files, everything is lost already. In some systems very little barriers exist for other users to completely delete whole scratch partitions. We know that the file name must follow the `*my_file* pattern anyway so changing the rest in a less-predictable way gains very little, the attacker can just look for the files named that way.

Comment: (too long)  If the directory is known then even if the file name is essentially random, the attacker may still know, what to attack and the whole approach must be considered carefully from a wider perspective.

Comment: Caveat in answer appreciated, but just to note: the attacks on predictable filenames (in shared temporary directories, say) aren't so much about _finding_ files used for communication but _creating_ them: Bob creates the file which Alice predictably is going to try to write to when talking to Charlie.